# Pandas: Is there a native way to sort rows by providing a list of index labels?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets take this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
L0 = ['d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c']
L1 = ['z','z','z','z','x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y']
L2 = [1,6,3,8,7,6,7,6,3,5,6,5]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":L0,"B":L1,"C":L2})
df = df.pivot(columns="A",index="B",values="C")
```

After pivoting the columns and rows are in alphabetical order.

Reordering the columns is easy and can be done with a custom list of column labels:

```
df = df[['d','a','b','c']]
```

But reordering the rows has no such direct function, the most elegant way I could think of was by using the column label functionality and transposing forth and back:

```
df = df.T[['z','x','y']].T
```

Doing this e.g. has no effect at all:

```
df.loc[['x','y','z'],:] = df.loc[['z','x','y'],:]
```

Is there no direct way to sort the rows of a dataframe by providing a custom list of index labels?

Comment: You can just do `df = df.loc[['z','x','y'],:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html), what is faster as `loc`:

For `index`:

```
idx = ['z','x','y']
df = df.reindex(idx)
print (df)
A  a  b  c  d
B            
z  6  3  8  1
x  6  7  6  7
y  5  6  5  3
```

Or:

```
idx = ['z','x','y']
df = df.reindex_axis(idx)
print (df)
A  a  b  c  d
B            
z  6  3  8  1
x  6  7  6  7
y  5  6  5  3
```

As [ssm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384397/pandas-is-there-a-native-way-to-sort-rows-by-providing-a-list-of-index-labels/43384414#comment73830523_43384397) pointed:

```
df = df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y'], :]
print (df)
A  a  b  c  d
B            
z  6  3  8  1
x  6  7  6  7
y  5  6  5  3
```

For columns:

```
cols = ['d','a','b','c']
df = df.reindex(columns=cols)
print (df)
A  d  a  b  c
B            
x  7  6  7  6
y  3  5  6  5
z  1  6  3  8

cols = ['d','a','b','c']
df = df.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
A  d  a  b  c
B            
x  7  6  7  6
y  3  5  6  5
z  1  6  3  8
```

---

Both:

```
idx = ['z','x','y']
cols = ['d','a','b','c']
df = df.reindex(columns=cols, index=idx)
print (df)
A  d  a  b  c
B            
z  1  6  3  8
x  7  6  7  6
y  3  5  6  5
```

**Timings**:

```
In [43]: %timeit (df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y'], ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']])
1000 loops, best of 3: 653 µs per loop

In [44]: %timeit (df.reindex(columns=cols, index=idx))
1000 loops, best of 3: 402 µs per loop
```

Only indexes:

```
In [49]: %timeit (df.reindex(idx))
The slowest run took 5.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 271 µs per loop

In [50]: %timeit (df.reindex_axis(idx))
The slowest run took 6.50 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 252 µs per loop


In [51]: %timeit (df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y']])
The slowest run took 5.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 418 µs per loop

In [52]: %timeit (df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y'], :])
The slowest run took 4.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 542 µs per loop
```

---

```
def pir(df):
    idx = ['z','x','y']
    a = df.index.values.searchsorted(idx)
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        df.values[a],
        df.index[a], df.columns
    )
    return df

In [63]: %timeit (pir(df))
The slowest run took 7.75 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: You nee to compare against just `df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y']]`  Otherwise not fair comparison.

Comment: It is same, `loc` is slowier. I think because `reindex` and `reindex_axis` is implemented mainly for it, `loc` is implemented more for selecting.

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: Try my new way.

Comment: OP wants `the most elegant way` and `numpy solution` obviously are not elegant ;)

Comment: Since I'm also working a lot with very large datasets I'm always interested in optimized `numpy` solutions as well, so go ahead.

Comment: @Khris - hmmm, so if need fastest, numpy solution wins.

Comment: For my current problem I wanted the simplest, but you never know when I will need the fastest in the future. :)

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using **`loc`** is a very natural way to do it

```
df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y']]

A  d  a  b  c
B            
z  1  6  3  8
x  7  6  7  6
y  3  5  6  5
```

You can assign it back to the dataframe with

```
df = df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y']]
```

---

Both axes in one go with `loc`

```
df.loc[['z', 'x', 'y'], ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']]

A  d  a  b  c
B            
z  1  6  3  8
x  7  6  7  6
y  3  5  6  5
```

---

A fast way to do it with **`numpy.searchsorted`**

```
l = list('zxy')
a = df.index.values.searchsorted(l)
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values[a],
    df.index[a], df.columns
)

A  d  a  b  c
B            
z  1  6  3  8
x  7  6  7  6
y  3  5  6  5
```